# Computing expectation in a biased random walk with absorbing barriers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose a person at point *x* on a natural number line with absorbing barriers at L and R takes steps towards R with probability *p* and towards L with probability *q*, I know how to compute the probabilities of hitting L and R, using the recurrence relation way.

My question is: given P(L) and P(R), will the expected # of steps taken until a barrier is hit be 1/P(L) + 1/P(R)? And if not, how can we compute it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that your guess can't be right by purely qualitative considerations: For $p=q=1/2$, starting in the middle between the barriers, you hit either barrier with probability $1/2$. Under the constraint $P(L)+P(R)=1$, your guess $1/P(L)+1/P(R)$ takes its minimum at $P(L)=P(R)=1/2$. But the expected time to reach a barrier should be at a maximum, not at a minimum, in the middle. The problem with your guess is that when you're close to one of the barriers, it's dominated by the contribution that corresponds to reaching the distant barrier, whereas the expected time in that case is dominated by the expected time to reach the nearby barrier.

You can calculate the expected time to reach a barrier using a recurrence relation, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307246/6622) for the case $p=q=1/2$.

Comment: Can you pl. give the general solution to the recurrence relation when q < p ?

Comment: @true: Where are you stuck?

Comment: $t_x$ = 1 + $\left(q*t_{x-1} + p*t_{x+1}\right)$. What is the general solution to this ?

Comment: @true: Are you aware of the method of solving linear recurrences using their characteristic equation? If not, how did you solve the recurrence you got for the probabilities?

Comment: The solution of the recurrence relation was given, and other parts of the problem needed to be solved using it.

Comment: Guess DIY called for. Dabbling in probability and combinatorics at the age of 75 is hopefully keeping my *brain* young, but self-study of dense tracts of math sure kills  *me* !

Comment: @true: Sorry, I was busy and hadn't read your previous comment -- I'll try to get back to you on this as soon as I find the time.