# Cheese, mouse and a cat

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it because I don't know where to start. 
If we have the following situation:

Room 1-Room 2-Room 3-Room 4-Room 5

There is a little mouse in room 4 and he always forgets in which room he has been when going to the next room. In room 5 there is a big hungry cat waiting for him and in room 1 there is cheese. What is the chance he will get the cheese and not being eaten by the cat?
My error solution:
If I go like $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4} +$ (endless possibilities). I know that this is not the way I should calculate it. This is I think a geometric distribution because it is memoryless. On the other hand I can use binomial distribution to calculate it but there are endless possibilities..

I just need a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the mouse stop moving if it gets to the cheese?

Comment: yes he does....

Comment: In your formulation, can the rat always go from Room X to Room Y for every $X\neq Y$, that is, for every two different rooms there is a door that connects them?

Comment: If you are in room 3, then you can go in room 2 and 4 etc. But if you are in room 2, you can't go in room 4 for example.

Comment: For a more general setting with more rooms, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288298/symmetric-random-walk-with-bounds?rq=1

Comment: You need to assume that the rat always moves and that the mouse chooses directions equally at random.

Comment: What rat? $\hspace{1cm}$

Comment: You can consider rat = mouse, since they're isomorphic :)

Comment: @Ross: That question treats the expected number of steps before eating or being eaten, not the probability for one of them occurring.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: If he started in Room $3$, symmetry shows that his probability of getting the cheese would be $\frac12$. Starting in Room $4$ he either reaches Room $3$ on his first move or falls prey to the cat, each with probability $\frac12$.

**Added:** I’m assuming that the rooms are arranged in a line, as in the diagram in the question, and that the mouse is equally likely to go to the left and to the right.

Comment: I don't think so.  He might just hang about in Rooms 2,3 and 4 forever.

Comment: @Tara That occurs with probability 0.

Comment: Did you take in account that the rat could enter in a infinite loop like Room 2-Room 3-Room 2-Room 3...

Comment: @TaraB: His probability of doing so is $0$.

Comment: @Brian Did OP specify that the probability of moving left is the same as of moving right?

Comment: @MJD:  Yeah, I just realised that!

Comment: @MJD: I’m assuming that that’s part of the import of *memoryless*.

Comment: At least I wasn't the only one. =]

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't agree.  A memoryless actor could be equipped with, say, a die that has "left" on two faces and "right" on four.

Comment: @MJD: Of course that’s possible. But in the absence of a statement to that effect, the default assumption seems to me to be a symmetric random walk.

Comment: Couldn't the little mouse just use its scent to figure this out? :P

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: By the symmetry the chance going to the next or the previous room is equal. But the thing that bothers me is that th amount of possibilities like room 2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2 and then 1 etc etc. Should I take in count the amount of possibilities or is that not relevant here? I think it is but I am not sure..

Comment: @Asa1789: The probability that the mouse stays in Rooms $2$-$4$ forever is $0$.

Comment: Calculate the chance that the mouse gets to Room 1 in exactly 3, 4, 5, etc, steps, then define a serie that depends on $n$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: I didn't ment that he stayed between two rooms forever but that there are many many possibilities and I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: Use factorials.

Comment: @Asa1789: The symmetry argument lets you avoid dealing with the various cases: you don’t have to handle them.

Comment: @ Gustavo Marra: getting in room 1 could be done even in 10^10 ways, right?

Comment: @Asa1789: There are infinitely many different ways to reach Room $1$.

Comment: Exactly @Asa1789. Though you probably could find an expression for the mouse to reach Room 1 in $n$ movements, or at least find a upper bound for it and show that it converges.

Comment: Thanks all of you! I will now try to use symmetry to solve the problem.

Comment: @Asa1789: You’re welcome. It really is the simplest solution, though there are certainly others that consider the process in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $p_k$ the probability that  the mouse will finally get the cheese when she sits in room $k$. Then
$$p_1=1,\quad p_2={1\over2}p_1 +{1\over 2}p_3,\quad p_3={1\over2}p_2+{1\over2} p_4,\quad p_4={1\over2} p_3+{1\over2}p_5, \quad p_5=0\ .$$
Now find $p_4$.